# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'market_value' ​

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot the ACF of the datasets but getting an error saying " AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'market_value' ."

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots as sgt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA
from scipy.stats.distributions import chi2
import seaborn as sns 
sns.set()

df_comp = pd.read_csv("Index2018.csv")
df_comp.date = pd.to_datetime(df_comp.date,dayfirst = True) 
df_comp.set_index("date",inplace = True)
df_comp['market value'] = df_comp.ftse

size = int(len(df_comp)*0.8)
df, df_test = df_comp.iloc[:size],df_comp.iloc[size:]
sgt.plot_acf(df.market_value, zero = False, lags = 40) 
plt.title("PACF", size = 24)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

That column is `"market value"`, note the space. Pandas lets you reference columns as dataframe attributes if the names are valid python variable names. Since there is a space, it can only be referenced by index. You could either name the column `"market_value"` or stick to using indexing `df["market value"]`.

Comment: I just found out that the underscore was missing ahahah Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is just because you have used the name incorrectly. You have used
**"df.market_value"** in which **"market_value"** does not match the value which you have assigned earlier in **df_comp['market value']** which is **'market value'**.

instead of:

> market_value in df.market_value

use:

> ['market value'] in df["market value"]